# A function within a structure. Why?

Tags: go

What is the use case/advantage of defining a function within a structure in go?

```
type demo struct {
    F func()
}
```

Comment: @TehSphinX Thanks for voting me down base on your assumptionn, and yes it is possible https://play.golang.org/p/AjFvfGDjRI

Answer (score 6):

I think that the best answer would be an example.

Look at [`Client.CheckRedirect`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.CheckRedirect) in the documentation.

```
type Client struct {
    // (...)
    CheckRedirect func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
}
```

This is a function that is being invoked whenever a `http.Client` has a redirect response. By the fact, that this function is a public property, you can set this when creating the `Client` object or afterwards and thus you can define custom behaviour on such case.

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    }
}
```

Function properties are just a delegates of custom behaviour (and not only!).

Another example would be creating an object which has an event.

```
type Example struct {
    EventHandler func(params []interface{})
}
```

You can specify a behaviour on that event by setting the `Example.EventHandler` property.

Comment: **"Function properties are a delegates of custom behavior"**. You nailed it there! I dig deeper into implementation of **checkRedirect** in [client.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go). When you declare a function withing a structure us do two things. First, you implement default behavior for declared function. Second you give a user freedom to override behavior of declared function. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @LukaszDynowski would you consider accepting this answer?

Answer (score -1):

It allows you to customize the function for a type without making it be from that type.